# How do we delete a shape that's already been created in Tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter

Consider:

```
from Tkinter import *


a = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(a, width = 500, height = 500)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100)
```

How do we delete this rectangle that's been created?

This is in reference to a game I am creating. It's a simple game where if the ball hits the block, the block should disappear. But if I do something like this:

```
class Block:
    def __init__(self,canvas,color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 110, 20, fill=color )
        self.id1 = canvas.create_rectangle(115, 10, 215, 20, fill=color)
        self.id2 = canvas.create_rectangle(220, 10, 320, 20, fill=color)
        self.id3 = canvas.create_rectangle(325, 10, 425, 20, fill=color)
        self.id4 = canvas.create_rectangle(430, 10, 530, 20, fill=color)
        self.id5 = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 150, 200, 160, fill=color)
        self.id6 = canvas.create_rectangle(350, 150, 450, 160, fill=color)
        self.x = 0
```

And then:

```
    def hit_block(self,pos):
        block_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.block.id)
        List = [block_pos]
        for i in List:
            if pos[0] >= i[0] and pos[2] <= i[2]:
                if pos[1] >= i[1] and pos[1] <= i[3]:
                    canvas.delete(block.id)
                    self.score()
                    global a
                    a += 1
                    return True
        return False
```

It doesn't work. How can I delete the block when the ball hits it?

Comment: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.delete-method

Comment: Have you read the documentation? How to do this is clearly documented. If not, why not? If so, did you not understand part of it? If that's the case, tell us what part you don't understand so we can focus our help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be solved by reading the official documentation

Comment: When I try to delete like the above answer, can't delete the border.
Instead of that, I rather use canvas.delete("all")
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839491/how-to-clear-tkinter-canvas

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assign the `create_rectangle()` to a variable, and then call [`canvas.delete()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.delete-method) on that variable:

```
from Tkinter import *


a = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(a, width = 500, height = 500)
canvas.pack()

myrect = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100)
canvas.delete(myrect) #Deletes the rectangle
```

Window before deletion:

[image: Picture before deletion]

Window after deletion:

[image: Picture after deletion]

Comment: Thanks, and that was something I was looking for, but now that Ive edited my question, could you help me out there as well?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion better option is add a Option `tags=` to function `create_rectangle()` and u can avoid creating new variables.

```
from Tkinter import *
a = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(a, width = 500, height = 500)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100, tags="square")
canvas.delete("square") #Deletes the rectangle wchich have tags option named "square"
```

> myrect = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100)

Btw. it's a problem when u "delete" an object from `myrect` to "create" them again in the same variable.